# Regex: match a character except at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to strip a character from a string, unless that character is at the beginning of a string.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
def strip_string(value):
  return re.sub(r"[^0-9\.]",'',value)

# strip_string('1-23') => '123'
```

I want to remove only the dashes that **aren't** the first character though:

`strip_string('-1-23') => '-123'`

I know how to target dashes that are the first character (`r"^-"`), but not the inverse.

Is it possible to do this, or do I need to go about it differently?

Comment: Hint: You have to look behind that there is not any character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to remove a character from a string that is not at the beginning is to use a `(?!^)` / `(?!\A)` negative lookahead. However, you can't just use `re.sub(r"(?!^)[^0-9.]",'',value)` as it won't remove non-hyphen chars either, while your scenario implies you expect to only keep a hyphen at the start.

Thus, in Python 3.5 and newer you may use (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XFpq2k/1)):

```
re.sub(r"^(-)|[^0-9.]+", r"\1", value)
```

Or, you may fall back to

```
re.sub(r"(?!^)-|[^0-9.-]+", "", value)   # This one is somewhat easier to understand
re.sub(r"-(?<!^-)|[^0-9.-]+", "", value) # This one is a bit more efficient
```

See [demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/XFpq2k/2) and [demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/XFpq2k/3).

Both `-(?<!^-)` and `(?!^)-` match a `-` that is not at the start of  a string.